# don't destroy datepicker after select date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use datepicker from jQuery UI.

Here you can see my initial code

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  minDate: 0,
  dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
$(this).text(dateText);
  },
  altField: '#startDate',
  altFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
},
$.datepicker.regional[ "ru" ]
);
```

After select date, datepicker destroy, but I don't need that datepicker destroy.

Comment: How `currDate` is assigned..?

Comment: oh, sorry, it is not needed. But it's still doesn't work.

Comment: Something else may be causing the problem... See this http://jsfiddle.net/XN3nm/ it works... Have you checked console..?

Comment: You don't understand my problem. It's works, but I need that after select date don't close/destroy datepicker.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zrrpb/. This is the closest i coould get to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, you understand what I mean. But it doesn't work in my project. I don't use <input> field. Here is example how it use http://jsfiddle.net/pirelly/TGy3s/

Comment: Here is a sample with two divs, http://jsfiddle.net/TGy3s/1/. let me know if it works for you so i can post an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you were facing was because of writing to the text property of the div, to which your date picker is attached. So the idea is to create two separate divs, one for the date picker and one for the selected value.

HTML:

```
Date: <div id='SelectedDate'></div>
<div id='fromDate'></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    minDate: 0,
    showAnim: '',
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#SelectedDate').text(dateText);
    },
    altField: '#startDate',
    altFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
},
$.datepicker.regional["ru"]);
```

Now you can add other elements in your HTML and do a .datepicker("destroy") on lcikc when you no longer need it.

EDIT: Forgot the Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/TGy3s/1/